# Is there a way of renaming the metrics and losses of a Keras model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a very big model with many losses and metrics.
When I do `print(np.array(self.model.metrics_names))`
I get this:

```
['loss' 'autoencoder_loss' 'autoencoder_loss' 'autoencoder_loss'
 'autoencoder_loss' 's_regularisation_phase_loss'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_loss' 's_regularisation_phase_loss'
 'z_regularisation_phase_loss' 'gen_regularisation_phase_loss'
 'z_regularisation_phase_loss' 'gen_regularisation_phase_loss'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_loss' 'autoencoder_categorical_accuracy'
 'autoencoder_output' 'autoencoder_categorical_accuracy_1'
 'autoencoder_output_1' 'autoencoder_categorical_accuracy_2'
 'autoencoder_output_2' 'autoencoder_categorical_accuracy_3'
 'autoencoder_output_3' 's_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy'
 's_regularisation_phase_output'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_output'
 's_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy_1'
 's_regularisation_phase_output_1'
 'z_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy'
 'z_regularisation_phase_output'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy_1'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_output_1'
 'z_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy_1'
 'z_regularisation_phase_output_1'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy_2'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_output_2'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_categorical_accuracy_3'
 'gen_regularisation_phase_output_3']
```

Is there a way to give them more meaningful names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names before each `_loss` and `_accuracy` came from the names of output layers.  If you want to modify this names you should rename the output layers.

Consider the following model.

```
input_ =  keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
x =  keras.layers.Dense(16)(input_)
output1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, name="output1")(x)
output2 = keras.layers.Dense(32, name="output2")(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[output1, output2])
model.compile(loss=["mse", "mae"], optimizer="adam", metrics={"output1":"accuracy","output2":"accuracy"})
```

Now `model.metrics_names` will give you the following list

```
['loss', 'output1_loss', 'output2_loss', 'output1_acc', 'output2_acc']
```